# Can routers operate as a "pure" switch?

Tags: networking

Recently, I configure a spare Lynksys router to work like a switch by doing the followings:

1. Give the wireless router (access point/switch) an ip address on the same network as DHCP server (router).
2. Disable DHCP, DNS, and firewall.
3. Plug in to one of the 4 LAN ports (not WAN or Internet port).

With this configuration, the Linksys router works similar to a switch. So Are routers = switches with extra features?

Since routers and switches operate at different layers, is it correct to assume, even with the configuration above, that routers are still dealing with packets and IP routing while switches deal with MAC address/Frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, typical SoHo "wireless routers" are switches with additional features. Inside a typical SoHo router, you will find an Ethernet switching chip connecting their LAN ports. Switching is typically done in software for their wireless interface.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that switches typically connect units inside a network, and routers connect networks. So you couldn't connect your hub/switch to your broadband modem because the modem is on an outside network, and hence the need for a router that can do NAT.

Regarding which layers of the stack switches work in, traditionally you are correct, hence part of the differences between routers and switches. However, as usual, things got complicated. Wikipedia says that more sophisticated switches open the packets at different levels. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch

Answer (score 0):

The "Wireless Router" is actual multiple devices: an Ethernet switch, a router, a wireless access point (WAP) and maybe a firewall (I am not sure about the firewall.).